# OpenGL Camera class

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

I'm trying to create a simple Camera class for OpenGL using C++. So it basically uses the following functions:

```
void setModelviewMatrix () {
            float m[16];
            Vector3 eVec(eye.x, eye.y, eye.z);
            m[0]=u.x;   m[4]=u.y;   m[8]=u.z;   m[12]=-eVec.dotProduct(u);
            m[1]=v.x;   m[5]=v.y;   m[9]=v.z;   m[13]=-eVec.dotProduct(v);
            m[2]=n.x;   m[6]=n.y;   m[10]=n.z;  m[14]=-eVec.dotProduct(n);
            m[3]=0;     m[7]=0;     m[11]=0;    m[15]=1.0;
            glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
            glLoadMatrixf(m);
    }
    void set (Point3 newEye, Point3 newLook, Vector3 newUp) {
            eye.set(newEye);
            n.set(eye.x-newLook.x, eye.y-newLook.y, eye.z-newLook.z);
            u.set(newUp.crossProduct(n));
            n.normalize();
            u.normalize();
            v.set(n.crossProduct(u));
            setModelviewMatrix();
    }
    void setShape (float vAng, float asp, float nearD, float farD) {
            viewAngle = vAng;
            aspect = asp;
            nearDist = nearD;
            farDist = farD;
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
            glLoadIdentity();
            gluPerspective(viewAngle, aspect, nearDist, farDist);       
    }
```

So I tested it by replacing the working standard camera setup (see below) with my new camera setup (below as well). From my point of view, the new setup does exactly the same thing as the old one. But still, the result is different: With the new setup the only thing I can see is a blank white screen and not the object that was displayed before. Why is that?

Old camera setup (working):

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho(-64/48.0, 64/48.0, -1.0, 1.0, 0.1, 100.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
gluLookAt(2.3, 1.3, 2, 0, 0.25, 0, 0, 1, 0);
```

New setup (not working):

```
Point3 eye = Point3(2.3, 1.3, 2);
Point3 look = Point3(0, 0.25, 0);
Vector3 up = Vector3(0, 1, 0);
cam.setShape(30.0f, 64.0f/48.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f);
cam.set(eye, look, up);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, the problem had nothing to do with the implementation of these methods. It was actually a problem with Visual Studio. As I switched from C to C++ and I didn't change the setup, the problem was caused by that. I tried implementing the camera functions in C and it worked.
Thanks for your help, though.

Comment: That makes no sense, switching from C to C++ is not going to transpose your matrix to make this camera work correctly. There must be something else.

Comment: Well I copied the code for setModelviewMatrix from my [textbook](http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Graphics-Using-OpenGL-Edition/dp/0131496700/ref=sr_1_9?ie=UTF8&qid=1384356609&sr=8-9&keywords=computer+graphics+with+opengl). I also asked my professor about it and he couldn't find any mistake. And when I used the same code with C instead of C++ it worked.
So I would guess, the code was correct and the problem is caused by C++ or Visual Studio.

Comment: I'm just wondering, what I am supposed to change in the Visual Studio Setup to make it work with C++...

Answer (score 3):

You have forgotten that OpenGL uses column-major matrices. Assuming those are basis vectors, they should each span a column instead of row. This is the layout that OpenGL uses for matrices when stored in memory:

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC534287.png

#### This ought to take care of your problem (*transposed 3x3 matrix*):

```
void setModelviewMatrix () {
        GLfloat m[16];
        m[0]=u.x;   m[4]=v.x;   m[ 8]=n.x;  m[12]=eye.x;
        m[1]=u.y;   m[5]=v.y;   m[ 9]=n.y;  m[13]=eye.y;
        m[2]=u.z;   m[6]=v.z;   m[10]=n.z;  m[14]=eye.z;
        m[3]=0.0f;  m[7]=0.0f;  m[11]=0.0f; m[15]=1.0f;
        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
        glLoadMatrixf(m);
}
```

You are free to use whatever memory layout you want if your matrix class does all of the calculations, but the second you pass a matrix to OpenGL it expects a particular layout. Even if you are using shaders, OpenGL expects matrix uniforms to be column-major by default.

Comment: u,v,n represent the axis of the coordinate system from the camera. And unfortunately, your suggestion doesn't solve the problem. I still have a blank screen.

Comment: @CGFoX: Well, I highly doubt that you want to use the dot product of those vectors as the translation component of your modelview matrix. I do not know what you were trying to accomplish there, I would suggest placing the eye point in the 4th column as is customary; see the updated answer.

Comment: @CGFoX: I also would not switch from an orthographic projection to a perspective projection at the same time you are trying to test your implementation of `LookAt (...)`. Limit major changes to one thing at a time, or you will wind up debugging the wrong thing more often than not.